# submitting forms inside iframe in jquery dialog

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

so I am currently using a dialog box with an iframe inside (page from same domain) to return a value from the iframe to the page the dialog is on. Everything works great except when I submit a form. When i submit the search form and try to click the a's to get the value of the id to the input nothing happens. Heres an example of what im doing.

heres the page with the dialog

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('a#booksearch_lnk').click(function(){
            $('.choosebookbox').dialog('open').css('display','block');
                $('#choosebookframe').contents().find('a.choosebook').click(function(){
                    // alert($(this).attr('id'));
                    $("#isbn").val($(this).attr('id'));
                    $('.choosebookbox').dialog("close");
                });
        });
       });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="choosebookbox" style="display:none">
<h4>Choose your first book</h4><div align="center" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"><iframe scrolling="no" id="choosebookframe" src="http://www.myurl.com/choosebook.php" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="100%"></iframe></div>
    </body>
```

and here is the iframe page...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:600px;height:600px;">
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search" style="width:150px"/>
<input type="submit" value="search" class="orangebtnsm" />
</form>
<? if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search = $_GET['search'];
 echo "search for $search";
 echo "<ul>";
 echo "<li><a id='2345676898' class='choosebook'>Book 5</a>";
  echo "<li><a id='1985563345' class='choosebook'>Book 6</a>";
 echo "</ul>";
}
?>
<ul>
<li><a id="1234567898" class="choosebook">Book 1</a></li>
<li><a id="2345676898" class="choosebook">Book 2</a></li>
<li><a id="9854645645" class="choosebook">Book 3</a></li>
<li><a id="1985563345" class="choosebook">Book 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say try using a future-proof event handler.

Swap

```
$('#choosebookframe').contents().find('a.choosebook').click(function(){...
```

With

```
$('#choosebookframe').contents().find('a.choosebook').live('click',function(){
```

I think the binding is being lost when the form is submitted.

Comment: that actually makes the whole thing not work. Without the live the links work before 'post' but with live nothing works.

Comment: I have decided to use .load instead of using an iframe. When i click on the links, nothing happens

Comment: are you loading the content from the same domain? check your console for errors.